# DataTable is being overwritten with another DataTable in WCF Web Service .Net 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, ado.net

I am experiencing an issue '' does not belong to table in the WCF web service. This is because of the overwritten datatable by another thread with other schema. I have debugged by implementing the logs and found that the whole schema and data was changed with another database call which was called after the first one in sequence. This is really surprised for me that how the memory instance of the first datatable object is overwritten with the second one when this is not declared as static. I used thread locking but unfortunately it doesn't work. I am quit sure this is MS bug, but there might be a solution which I don't know so far.

Here is the sequence of method calls:
First I fill the datatable with user credentials for user authentication, this datatable has only three columns and one row.
Second I fill another datatable with some other data which is required to process the request, then I fill one more table which is also required to process the request.

Sometimes, the error pops up on the first datatable that '' does not belong to the table and sometimes it is appeared on the second datatable. When I logged the table schema it was totally changed with the second one.

Here is the code of first datatable:

```
public UserCredentials GetUserCredentials(string userName)
     {   
        try
        {
            UserCredentials userCredentials = null;

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable("User");
                    cmd.CommandText = "dbo.[stored procedure]";
                    cmd.Connection = this.connection;
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", userName);

                    using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                    {
                        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                        sda.Fill(dt);
                    }

                    if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        userCredentials = new UserCredentials();
                        userCredentials.UserName = userName;
                        userCredentials.SiteID = dt.Rows[0]["SiteID"].ToString();
                        **userCredentials.Password = dt.Rows[0]["Passphrase"].ToString();**
                    }
                }

            return userCredentials;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
     }
```

Second datatable:

```
public GatewayProfile GetGatewayProfile(string siteID)
        {
            Int64 gatewayID = 0;
            string submitterID = "";
            GatewayProfile gatewayProfile = null;

            try
            {
                this.OpenConnection();

                DataTable dtGateway = new DataTable("GTDetails");
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "dbo.[stored procedure]";
                    cmd.Connection = this.connection;
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SiteID", siteID);

                    using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                    {
                        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                        sda.Fill(dtGateway);
                    }
                }

                if (dtGateway != null && dtGateway.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    gatewayProfile = new GatewayProfile();

                    if (Convert.ToBoolean(dtGateway.Rows[0]["IsDefault"]) == false)
                    {
                        gatewayID = Convert.ToInt64(dtGateway.Rows[0]["GatewayID"]);
                        submitterID = dtGateway.Rows[0]["SubmitterID"].ToString();
                    }

                    DataTable dtRoute = new DataTable("RTDetails");
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                    {
                        cmd.CommandText = "dbo.[stored procedure]";
                        cmd.Connection = this.connection;
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GatewayID", gatewayID);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SubmitterID", submitterID);

                        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                        {
                            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                            sda.Fill(dtRoute);
                        }
                    }

                    if (dtRoute != null && dtRoute.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        gatewayProfile.GatewayID = Convert.ToInt64(dtRoute.Rows[0]["GatewayID"]);
                        gatewayProfile.SubmitterID = dtRoute.Rows[0]["SubmitterID"].ToString().Trim();
                        **gatewayProfile.ReceiverID = dtRoute.Rows[0]["ReceiverID"].ToString().Trim();**
                        gatewayProfile.AuthInfo = ReplaceDBNull(dtRoute.Rows[0]["AuthInfo"], "").Trim();
                        gatewayProfile.SecurityInfo = ReplaceDBNull(dtRoute.Rows[0]["SecurityInfo"], "").Trim();
                    }
                }

                return gatewayProfile;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally 
            {
                this.CloseConnection();
            }
        }
```

Third datatable

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = "dbo.[stored procedure]";
    cmd.Connection = this.connection;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", param1);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param2", param2);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param3", param3);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param4", param4);

    using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
    {
        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
        sda.Fill(dt);
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance if someone help me out to get this issue resolved.

Comment: None of your code snippets show you initializing `dt`. If this is an instance field and you're only initializing it in the constructor, and these three snippets are from three instance methods which are called on the same object, then yes, this will happen. We don't really have enough context to tell at the moment though.

Comment: This is because I have not posted the complete code here, this code is only of where I am filling the datatable object and these are three different methods of a single class. Yes, dt is the instance variable of the DataTable class but it is initialized separately for each method not in the constructor.

Comment: So you've omitted vital code and context. And if these methods are being run concurrently, then the assignment to dt in one thread will affect uses of dt in the other thread. Why is this an instance variable at all?

Comment: As I explained earlier that I have three methods in the DL of WCF web service and each of them returns datatable separately. And datatable variables are initialized in each method separately. For example: DataTable dt = new DataTable("User"), so the scope of this  dt variable is only within the method in which this is declared, right? But the problem is sometimes the first dt variable is overwritten with the schema and data which was filled by other method and this schema and data was never in the scope of first method.

Comment: And this is very unfortunate that how first datatable is overwritten with the other one when it is not in the shared scope.

Comment: So when you said it's an "instance variable" you actually meant "local variable"? Can you see how it's basically impossible for us to answer the question with this crucial information being absent or incorrect? This is what I was asking for in the very first comment - more context, accurately described. If you'd provided all the relevant code in the first place, this wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Yes, there might be a conflict to explain and understand the instance, member, class and local variables. Anyhow, these are all three local variables which are declared and initialized within each method independently. Unfortunately, I am unable to post the complete code here in comments because of character limit. I can send you via email if you are interested to see the complete code.

Comment: We don't necessarily need the complete code, but we need everything that's *relevant* - which definitely includes the declaration and initialization of the variable. It's still not clear why you earlier claimed it's an instance variable if it's actually a local variable - or what you mean by a "conflict" in this sense.

Comment: Instance mean, the dt variable is the instance of the DataTable class but it doesnt mean that its a member or class variable. But I understand your point that you were considering it as member variable. Anyhow, how can send you the relevant code?

Comment: I have updated the code in my first post; please see and help me out to get this issue resolved.

Comment: Okay, that's at least better - it's definitely worth trying to avoid using the term "instance variable" if that's not what you mean. Next, it seems like you're using a *connection* which is shared within the instance. Is there any reason for that? I would definitely just rely on the connection pool - create a new `SqlConnection` in each call. At that point, I can't see that you'd have any shared state, so you should be fine. Where exactly are you getting the exception? Could you include it in the question? Also note that having try/catch blocks like that just hides information - get rid of 'em

Comment: I have added the ** in front of LOCs where I am getting the errors and this is a random error, sometimes it pops up in the first function and sometime it is in the second method. There is no specific reason to use the shared connection, but would you feel that the shared connection may cause of this problem? this is very strange for me if this is the problem.

Comment: It wouldn't be strange to me. If you start one query on a connection while you're still trying to read data from a previous query, that could certainly cause issues. The exact details of why it shows up in this particular way might require a bit of digging, but fundamentally you don't *want* to requests on the same connection, so it's better just not to share it. Trust the connection pool to make this efficient.

Comment: Okay, Let me try to use separate connection for each call and then will update you on this. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I have implemented a separate connection for each call but unfortunately, it didn't work and still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured this issue out by putting a lots of efforts in a couple of weeks and found the detailed documentation of the SqlDataAdapter here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810286.aspx that how it works, but somehow the behavior of the SqlDataAdapter is the same with local DataTable variables as it is with the member or instance variables which should never be the same because both types of variables have their own separate memory space and can never be overwritten. I have also posted a bug to MS but didn't get any answer so far.

There are two workarounds of this problem.

1- Must define the DataTableMappings and DataColumnMappings for the SqlDataAdapter whenever you want to manage concurrency and multithreading.

2- Use SqlDataReader with separate connection for each call

Answer (score 0):

If the `dt` is shared between the threads, then you have to synchronize the access to it, probably using `Monitor` or `lock`.

If not shared, try using three different `DataTable` for each.

Your code snippet and description are not enough to visualize the complete scenario.

Comment: As I explained earlier that dt is not shared nor using the same dt for all three methods. Each method is using its own datatable dt which is initialized within the scope of each method but unfortunately somehow its overwritten by another method which does not make any sense.

Comment: Please post the exact stack trace you encountered.

Comment: This is all that I have logged in stack trace: Column '<column name>' does not belong to table RTUserCred. Stack Trace: at System.Data.DataRow.GetDataColumn(String columnName) at System.Data.DataRow.get_Item(String columnName) at WCF.Data.DataService.GetUserCredentials(String userName)